# Magento 2 - How to add onclick on checkbox in admin grid?

Tags: magento2, grid, checkbox

I want to add 'onclick' attribute on checkboxes, added through below code.

```
$this->addColumn(
    'customer_entity_id',
    [
        'header' => __(''),
        'index' => 'entity_id',
        'filter' => false,
        'sortable' => false,
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'field_name' => 'customer_entity_id[]',
        'values'=>$this->_getCustomerIds()
    ]
);
```

I have tried adding 'onclick' and 'action' but this are also not working.